# How to use GetType against static class with string name?

Tags: c#

I am having trouble trying to figure out how to GetType and then look if it has a property with GetProperty and need some help.  In this project there is a static class:

```
public static class Schema
{
   public static readonly CustomerTable Customers = new CustomerTable();
   public static readonly InvoiceTable Invoices = new InvoiceTable();
}

public class CustomerTable()
{
   public string Id { get; }
   public string Name { get; }
}
```

I have in a method the static read only name string coming in such as "Customers" that I need to check if that object CustomerTable has the field Id in it.  If I did not have the string I would be using for example:

```
var entity = Schema.Customers.GetType();
var hasId = entity.GetProperty("Id");
```

I just need to know if that is null where the "Id" is not a property do something.

Thanks all for any help.

Comment: You code seems right to me, have you tried it out? Did something go wrong?

Comment: Hey gunr I only have the string not the object.  Coming my method I have string "Customers" the var entity line is if I knew the object was Customers how I would get it.  In this case I only have the static readonly string.

Comment: @user2208746 your code doesn't even compile. How could you have two fields with the same name?

Comment: Are you aware that the `Customers` member(s) in `Schema` is a Field, not a Property?

Answer (score 2):

This ought to work (assuming your string is called `fieldName`):

```
var hasId = typeof(Schema)
    .GetField(fieldName, BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
    .FieldType.GetProperty("Id") != null;
```

Comment: This worked you guys rock.  Thanks so much.  @StriplingWarrior and others who commented.  I really appreciate it I was struggling with this one.

Comment: No problem. If this answers your question, remember to mark the answer correct so other people know you're not still looking for help.